# In Gitlab CI/CD, how to commit and publish the docker container that is running our stages

Tags: docker, automation, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am learning to work with gitlab CI/CD using docker executor.

Below is my `gitlab-ci.yml` file.

```yaml
image: registry.gitlab.com/vbrin-office/components/karma-tests

stages:
  - test

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - node --version
    - git --version
    - pwd
    - ls
    - cd /karmatests
    - ls
    - npx karma start
```

Each time when the pipeline is finished executing, I would like to commit the container and push it to the GitLab registry so that I can access it later.

Since we are actually inside the docker container for which I want to create an image. How could I do that? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is, but the image must have a certain name relative to your gitlab registry path. You can do something like this :

```
docker-build:
  stage: package
  script:
    - docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest .
    - docker tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
  only:
    - master
```

This will only push the image when the pipeline runs on your master branch.

Comment: Can you explain this in detail? Does "docker build ." command creates image from the current directory with all the files in it?  Does it have the contents I run in the previous stage? Or should I have to create an artifact?

Comment: It creates an image based on a dockerfile present in the same directory. The . stands for the path where to place the image.

Comment: So the docker container in which each stage of the pipeline gets executed, does it have the dockerfile inside it?

Comment: Yes, it pulls the code from the repository, you can check the logs to see.

Comment: This answer seems bogus. How would docker find the image here ? What dockerfile are we talking about ?

Comment: This was actually tested and it is working. The image is built on the first script line. We are talking about the dockerfile present in the code's repository.