# Recover docker image after a gitlab-ci run

Tags: docker, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

Let's say I build a docker image and then run some CI build like this:

```
stages:
  - create_builder_image
  - test

Create Builder Image:
  stage: create_builder_image
  script:
    - export DOCKER_BRANCH_TAG=$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    # do stuff to build the image, using cache to speed it up
    - docker push $GITLAB_IMAGE/builder:$DOCKER_BRANCH_TAG

Run Tests:
  image: $GITLAB_IMAGE/builder:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
  stage: build
  script:
    # build some stuff in the image
```

Then I want to push the resulting image, with the builded stuff inside

```
docker-package:
  stage: package
  script:
    - docker commit ?
    - docker push dockerhub:latest
```

That may not be possible at all.

Similar to [In Gitlab CI/CD, how to commit and publish the docker container that is running our stages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63580823/in-gitlab-ci-cd-how-to-commit-and-publish-the-docker-container-that-is-running)

Comment: This isn't really possible as described. Though, you can probably accomplish what you're trying to do using the Dockerfile.

Comment: The idea is to no rewrite the yml of the build part. A solution could be recover the build as an artifact and then copy the artefact in the original docker image using a Dockerfile.